# GeForce 845M for external display (2560x1440)

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

Can a GeForce 845M (laptop graphics card) run an external monitor with a resolution of 2560x1440?
Will it go smoothly (not gaming)?
Can it also simultaneous render the display of laptop 1920x1080?

Answer (score 0):

For higher resolutions you should consider gpus with higher horsepower because number of pixels processed affects workload of the gpu directly. It will probably play videos buy gaming will be difficult for a mid range card.